# A Python Script that runs without issue in ArcGIS Pro fails in PyCharm

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, pycharm

I have created a script in ArcGIS Pro to delete and copy some datasets from one location to another. It works flawlessly when run through ArcGIS Pro. When I attempt to run the script in PyCharm, however, it tells me that several of the variable set in the script do not exist, even though they clearly do.

Immediately after the script fails in PyCharm, I can run it in ArcGIS Pro without issue. Here is the script in question:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Local Variables

TargetDB = "C:\\Users\\~user~\\AppData\\Roaming\\Esri\\ArcGISPro\\Favorites\\OCGIS21 - Vector - ~user~.sde"

# Delete Datasets - these datasets will be deleted by the script
Del_Address = "C:\\Users\\~user~\\AppData\\Roaming\\Esri\\ArcGISPro\\Favorites\\OCGIS21 - Vector - ~user~.sde\\OCGIS21_Vector.DBO.Address\\OCGIS21_Vector.DBO.SiteAddressPoints"
Del_Zoning = "C:\\Users\\~user~\\AppData\\Roaming\\Esri\\ArcGISPro\\Favorites\\OCGIS21 - Vector - ~user~.sde\\OCGIS21_Vector.DBO.LandUsePlanning\\OCGIS21_Vector.DBO.Zoning_County"
Del_Parcels = "C:\\Users\\~user~\\AppData\\Roaming\\Esri\\ArcGISPro\\Favorites\\OCGIS21 - Vector - ~user~.sde\\OCGIS21_Vector.DBO.ParcelPublishing\\OCGIS21_Vector.DBO.TaxParcel"
Del_Buildings = "C:\\Users\\~user~\\AppData\\Roaming\\Esri\\ArcGISPro\\Favorites\\OCGIS21 - Vector - ~user~.sde\\OCGIS21_Vector.DBO.ReferenceData\\OCGIS21_Vector.DBO.BuildingFootprints"
Del_Roads = "C:\\Users\\~user~\\AppData\\Roaming\\Esri\\ArcGISPro\\Favorites\\OCGIS21 - Vector - ~user~.sde\\OCGIS21_Vector.DBO.ReferenceData\\OCGIS21_Vector.DBO.RoadCenterline"

# Target Datasets - these datasets contain the feature classes to be overwritten

OVR_Address = "C:\\Users\\~user~\\AppData\\Roaming\\Esri\\ArcGISPro\\Favorites\\OCGIS21 - Vector - ~user~.sde\\OCGIS21_Vector.DBO.Address"
OVR_LandUsePlanning = "C:\\Users\\~user~\\AppData\\Roaming\\Esri\\ArcGISPro\\Favorites\\OCGIS21 - Vector - ~user~.sde\\OCGIS21_Vector.DBO.LandUsePlanning"
OVR_ParcelPublishing = "C:\\Users\\~user~\\AppData\\Roaming\\Esri\\ArcGISPro\\Favorites\\OCGIS21 - Vector - ~user~.sde\\OCGIS21_Vector.DBO.ParcelPublishing"
OVR_ReferenceData = "C:\\Users\\~user~\\AppData\\Roaming\\Esri\\ArcGISPro\\Favorites\\OCGIS21 - Vector - ~user~.sde\\OCGIS21_Vector.DBO.ReferenceData"

# Update Features - These Feature Classes will overwrite the current version on the live database

NewAddress = "C:\\Users\\~user~\\AppData\\Roaming\\Esri\\ArcGISPro\\Favorites\\OCGIS21 - Vector - DEV - ~user~.sde\\OCGIS_21_Vector_DEV.DBO.Address\\OCGIS_21_Vector_DEV.DBO.SiteAddressPoints"
NewZoning = "C:\\Users\\~user~\\AppData\\Roaming\\Esri\\ArcGISPro\\Favorites\\OCGIS21 - Vector - DEV - ~user~.sde\\OCGIS_21_Vector_DEV.DBO.LandUsePlanning\\OCGIS_21_Vector_DEV.DBO.Zoning_County"
NewParcels = "C:\\Users\\~user~\\AppData\\Roaming\\Esri\\ArcGISPro\\Favorites\\OCGIS21 - Vector - DEV - ~user~.sde\\OCGIS_21_Vector_DEV.DBO.ParcelWorking\\OCGIS_21_Vector_DEV.DBO.TaxParcel_Working"
NewBuildings = "C:\\Users\\~user~\\AppData\\Roaming\\Esri\\ArcGISPro\\Favorites\\OCGIS21 - Vector - DEV - ~user~.sde\\OCGIS_21_Vector_DEV.DBO.ReferenceData\\OCGIS_21_Vector_DEV.DBO.BuildingFootprints"
NewRoads = "C:\\Users\\~user~\\AppData\\Roaming\\Esri\\ArcGISPro\\Favorites\\OCGIS21 - Vector - DEV - ~user~.sde\\OCGIS_21_Vector_DEV.DBO.ReferenceData\\OCGIS_21_Vector_DEV.DBO.RoadCenterline"

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Script

import arcpy
import os

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Block new connections and disconnect users

print("OCGIS21_Vector is no longer accepting connections")
arcpy.AcceptConnections(TargetDB, False)
time.sleep(5)
print("Disconnecting all users")
arcpy.DisconnectUser(TargetDB, "ALL")
time.sleep(5)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Delete old version of data

print("Deleting current copy of OCGIS21 data")
arcpy.management.Delete("'Del_Address';'Del_Zoning';'Del_Parcels';'Del_Buildings';'Del_Roads'")
print(arcpy.GetMessages(0))
time.sleep(5)

#---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copy new version of data in place of old


#Address
print("Replacing Address file")
arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(NewAddress, OVR_Address, "SiteAddressPoints")
print(arcpy.GetMessages(0))
time.sleep(5)
#Zoning
print("Replacing Zoning file")
arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(NewZoning, OVR_LandUsePlanning, "Zoning_County")
print(arcpy.GetMessages(0))
time.sleep(5)
#Parcels
print("Replacing Parcel file")
arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(NewParcels, OVR_ParcelPublishing, "TaxParcel")
print(arcpy.GetMessages(0))
time.sleep(5)
#Buildings
print("Replacing Building file")
arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(NewBuildings, OVR_ReferenceData, "BuildingFootprints")
print(arcpy.GetMessages(0))
time.sleep(5)
#Roads
print("Replacing Road Centerline file")
arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(NewRoads, OVR_ReferenceData, "RoadCenterline")
print(arcpy.GetMessages(0))
time.sleep(5)

print("Allowing users to connect to the database again")
arcpy.AcceptConnections(TargetDB, True)

print("Done")
```

I suspect that the issue comes from this line in particular:

```
arcpy.management.Delete("'Del_Address';'Del_Zoning';'Del_Parcels';'Del_Buildings';'Del_Roads'")
```

My thought is that it doesn't see each variable called out since they are separated by semi colons, however according to the ArcGIS Pro documentation, that is how you are supposed to enter it, and as I mentioned previously, it runs perfectly through ArcGIS Pro's Python window.

When run through the PyCharm Python console, I get the following messages:

```
OCGIS21_Vector is no longer accepting connections
Disconnecting all users
Deleting current copy of OCGIS21 data
Start Time: Tuesday, September 13, 2022 3:34:56 PM
WARNING 000110: Del_Address does not exist
WARNING 000110: Del_Zoning does not exist
WARNING 000110: Del_Parcels does not exist
WARNING 000110: Del_Buildings does not exist
WARNING 000110: Del_Roads does not exist
Succeeded at Tuesday, September 13, 2022 3:34:56 PM (Elapsed Time: 0.01 seconds)
Replacing Address file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\~user~\Desktop\Python Scripts\Copy Working Data to Production\OCGIS_Vector_Update.py", line 58, in <module>
    arcpy.conversion.FeatureClassToFeatureClass(NewAddress, OVR_Address, "SiteAddressPoints")
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 3204, in FeatureClassToFeatureClass
    raise e
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 3201, in FeatureClassToFeatureClass
    retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(*gp_fixargs((in_features, out_path, out_name, where_clause, field_mapping, config_keyword), True)))
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 512, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000258: Output C:\Users\~user~\AppData\Roaming\Esri\ArcGISPro\Favorites\OCGIS21 - Vector - ~user~.sde\OCGIS21_Vector.DBO.Address\OCGIS21_Vector.DBO.SiteAddressPoints already exists
Failed to execute (FeatureClassToFeatureClass).


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue comes from the Delete line.
In your script at lines 7-11 you have defined variables Del_Address, Del_Zoning, … while at the the delete function you are passing in strings 'Del_Address', 'Del_Zoning', …

Try coding your delete command like this:
`arcpy.management.Delete([Del_Address,Del_Zoning,Del_Parcels,Del_Buildings,Del_Roads])`

Comment: I apologize for the delay. Just got back to this problem and this solved it. Thank you so much! I was pulling my hair out on this! I wish I knew a way to submit a complaint about ESRI's documentation because it seems to be teaching people the wrong way to format the code.

Comment: For any documentation topic, you can click on the "Feedback on this topic?" link which appears at the bottom of the page. If you fill out that form, it will be sent directly to the editor who manages that particular topic, they do regularly review and modify the help based on provided feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you should use [`arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/arcpy/classes/env.htm) at the top of your script. In the Pro app it's pulling this setting from your preferences, outside of the app it's not.

Comment: Overwrite output shouldn't matter in this case because I have set the script up to delete the old layers and then export the new layers. I did test this just to make sure and it still did not work. Thanks for the suggestion!